# Can Clairvoyant sight be used to see someone in another dimension?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

The form ability can be used to see someone one has met recently regardless of the physical distance. So far I understand it, but what is about another dimension thus in the shadow or underworld while you are in the material world?

Does it still work?

Also does it work if the other one is intangible and (normally) invisible to one?

Comment: Just a quick note : intangible means imperceptible by the sense of touch. Nothing in the word implies invisibility (see The Flash or Superman for a popular example of this).

Comment: @Nigralbus Superman is intangible?

Comment: Superman, like the Flash, can vibrate his molecules at a frequency that enables him to phase through most matter. This can blur his shape but does not make him invisible.

http://comicvine.gamespot.com/superman/4005-1807/forums/can-superman-vibrate-through-things-1500666/

Comment: reformulated the phrase to be more clear. although I wonder why nobody just edited it^^

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answer, there are three questions at the heart:

1. Target is in another dimension:

For a more Demon-sourced answer, let's look at the Process: Eliminator Cannon (Flowers of Hell, page 128.) It explicitly states "No physical range, but crossing into a different plane of existence (ie, Underworld) passes the Demon out of range."

According to CoD/WoD cosmology in general, different realms of existence cannot interact - the Demon and target must be in the same plane of reality.

2. Target is supernaturally concealed:

This form ability allows a Demon to see a person in their location (or location.) So we have two stipulations:

- Demon Doug is trying to look for Nosferatu Nick. Nick is at the park, wearing his favorite band shirt, in full Obfuscate.

When Doug tries to look at Nick, he can effortlessly see the empty park. If he wants to try and actually tell what Nick is wearing, that would then be trying to pierce the Obfsucate, and then the Clash of Wills**.

- The other stipulation would be Doug wants to look at the park as a location, but Nick has used advanced Obfuscate to hide it.

In that case, Clairvoyant Sight would turn up nothing, although potentially, a Clash of Wills. Personally though, Doug should prolly get suspicious if his favorite park is suddenly "gone."

3. Target is in Twilight

Twilight is different because Twilight is not a separate plane, but a unique way to exist. Since Angels interact with Twilight a lot, it's worth breaking down as a special case.

The easiest way to describe Twilight is that it's a different physical "language." For example, Doug looks into a room where there are three horses and vier Pferde. He sees 3 animals, because he can't comprehend the others. Bound Barry (thanks to his Geist, Gary) can see all 7 animals.

Assuming Doug has no way to see into Twilight, if he tried to focus on someone in Twilight, he would again see the location with "no one" there.

** Clash of wills applies when two preternatural creatures attempt conflicting powers. Eg, Mage Mary tries to see the aura of Beast Betty while Betty tries to go unnoticed. Mary can only see the aura if Betty is noticed, and Betty can't go unnoticed if Mary is studying her aura. Thus, Clash of Wills to determine who wins.

AFAIR, Demons do not have an easy way to pierce supernatural illusions (like Vampires' Obfus-"don't look at me"-cate.) However, I'm including it as an option because it would make sense.

A "see through illusions" power would likely be a custom Exploit, though - from the GM's perspective, seeing a "normal human" perfectly watch an invisible Vampire would sure seem abnormal, and surely be flagged for later review.

Comment: I actually drew the opposite conclusion from Eliminator Cannon.
The very fact that *this* ability mentions that it does not work across dimensions, suggests that it is the default assumption that demon abilities do.

Comment: @LyndonWhite That is a reasonable argument to make; however, I feel that such an interpretation lends itself to creating more unforeseen consequences. For example, using Summon (core), a Demon could summon a freshly captured human out of Faerie, magically bypassing all that normally encompasses. Or using Mistaken Identity (flowers of hell), a Demon could cause people to confuse a taxi driver with an unmanifested spirit of death.

I feel like a more reasonable explanation why the Eliminator Cannon has this disclaimer was more likely a very interesting playtesting session.

Comment: Either way, I still feel like the core idea of "Twilight Detonator <==> Twilight Explosive" still conveys the correct idea of "Twilight Eyes <==> seeing someone in Twilight"

Comment: @C Geist: A good point.

Answer (score 2):

No.

[Disclaimer] I do not own Demon: The Descent.

I would rule that being in Twilight (or the Astral Realms, etc) is not a matter of physical distance, but metaphysical distance. A power worded "view the target wherever they are" would be allowed to view across dimensions.

Depending on the source of the intangibility, one is not necessarily invisible. If the invisibility is natural, I would rule that the Demon could sense the location but not see the individual (thus, knowing the power worked). If supernatural concealment is in use, consider Clash of Wills.

Optional: If the power requires a roll, consider allowing exceptional successes to pierce through into other dimensions if needed.